# Where can I find the stats for a magic item that produces magically delicious spices?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dungeons-and-dragons, magic-items, product-identification

I remember reading somewhere about a magic jar that produced an inexhaustible supply of spices that magically made anything cooked with them taste fantastic. It didn't change the mechanical effects of eating the food: poisons would still be poisonous, magic food would still have its effect, rations would still work normally, they'd all just taste better. I think the book it was in was for 3.5, but references from either 3.0, 3.5, or Pathfinder will work. I don't even much care if its the same item I read about before, so long as the functionality and fluff are fairly close.

Comment: Relevant Stack Q&As: [Pricing items as a DM](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31960) and [How can market price of magic items be calculated from crafting price?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/29844)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Spice Jar](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/items.php?ID=4133) from the Ferun setting is close to what you describe. It does however provide some bonuses aside from good tasting food.

A Pathfinder solution could easily be created using Wonderous Items rules. With DM approval any item can be created.

This item would likely be a continuous *[prestidigitation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation)* effect. Which by [the magic item GP value estimation chart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values) means it would cost Spell Level (*prestidigitation* is level 0 so this would be ½) × Caster Level (1) × 2000 which would make this item cost a low 1000 gold.

I used Prestidigitation because one of the abilities it has is:

> It can chill, warm, or flavor 1 pound of nonliving material

The item could easily be fluffed as producing a powder that flavors food to perfection.

Comment: As Avestron noted in the comments, if you limit the effect to flavoring food, you could easily argue a more potent effect than prestidigitation normally offers.

Comment: Since Prestidigitation does a lot of things, and this item would be using only one single effect from those, I would also reduce the price by half. (ok, or what @DavidWilkins suggested)

Answer (score 7):

From *Dragon* #73, for AD&D 2nd Edition:

> **Pan of Spicing**
>
> A 9-inch, round iron pan with the runic "S"
> embossed on the handle. Any food fried in this
> pan is magically spiced to the cook's taste—quite
> a boon in areas where spice is scarce.